# Javascript native/elegant way to strip properties from object

Tags: javascript

I would like to know if there is a native/elegant way to do this:

```
var object = {
    value: 1,
    desc: 'an object',
    method: function(){
        return this.description + ' with value: ' + this.value;
    },
};
var onlyProperties = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object));
```

As you can see I just want the properties without any methods in it. The above code works but it feels wrong to do it this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not looking for a recursive solution, here's a simple way to do it.

```
for (var i in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i) && typeof obj[i] === 'function') {
        delete obj[i];
    }
}
```

If you want a copy without functions:

```
var copy = {};
for (var i in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i) && typeof obj[i] !== 'function') {
        copy[i] = obj[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: I like your solution better than mine. +1.

Comment: Thanks! I am touched :)

Comment: i often overlook and underuse the delete keyword in js. So in addition i'd like to add this for future readers: http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/

Answer (score 1):

The native way is something like this:

```
var foo = {
    /* stuff*/
};

var onlyProperties = {};

for (var bar in foo) {
    if (typeof foo[bar] != "function") {
        onlyProperties[bar] = foo[bar];
    }
}
```

This way you keep both the original object and the new one containing only its non-function members.

Answer (score 0):

and what about this returns function calls?

```
var obj = {
  value: 1,
  desc: 'an object',
  method: function(){ return this.desc + ' with value ' + this.value; }
};
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj)); // "{"value":1,"desc":"an object"}"
```

If removing the method calls is your aim, `JSON.stringify` should be fine as-is. If you *really* want granularity:

```
JSOS.stringify(obj, function(k,v){
  // testing for `typeof x === 'function' really won't get hit,
  // but this does give you an example of how to proceed.
  return (typeof v === 'function' ? undefined : v);
});
```

You can use the [`replacer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_native_JSON#The_replacer_parameter) parameter to have more control over what's serialized.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var p in object) {
  if (object.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
    if (typeof object[p] === 'function') delete object[p];
  }
}
```